# How to rerun a specific stage only in YAML pipeline?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am working on a YAML pipeline POC. Let say this pipeline has 3 stages:

A -> B -> C (B depends on A, C depends on B)

All of these stages succeeded. I notice that if I rerun stage B, after stage B finished, it would also rerun stage C. I have to cancel it manually.

Is it possible to disable this automatic process, and rerun stage B only?

Comment: if you link your stage to environment with approval it wont be trigger automatically

Comment: So you mean link stage C to an environment with approval, is it? But this means stage C is waiting for approval and we still need to cancel it.

Comment: Yes you are right but it wont start automatically.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `System.StageAttempt` predefined variable to handle that, you may run into side effect tho: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services